# Change value of Preprocessor Directives in a .ino file using sed and jq

Tags: sed, jq

I am trying to figure out a way to use a `conf.json` file where I may have a *key : value* such as

```
SAMPLE_RATE : 1000
```

and I would like to same use this value to change the preprocessor directives defines in an Arduino Sketch such as (`test.ino`)

```
#define SAMPLE_RATE_SENSOR (100)
```

to be set from `(100)` to `(1000)`

My current try:

```
cat conf.json | jq .[] | sed -i -e '/SAMPLE_RATE_SENSOR/s/[0-9]/...how to get the jq value here ..../ test.ino
```

As a basic test I tried

```
sed -i -e '/SAMPLE_RATE_SENSOR/s/[0-9]/1000/' test.ino
```

but there is not change to the file itself.

### Aim

My Aim is actually to use a `conf` file to be sent to an Arduino Yun where a python will extract conf. info and change the Sketch with the Sample values accordingly and reprogram the microcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you have everything working the way you want it, I'd suggest taking one step at a time:

```
VALUE=$(jq .SAMPLE_RATE conf.json)
sed -i.bak -e "/SAMPLE_RATE_SENSOR/s/[0-9][0-9]*/$VALUE/" test.ino
```

Comment: the `bak` seems to be a problem for me. Is that an Option in `sed`?

Comment: It should have been -i.bak # this specifies the suffix to use for the backup